# Multiplayer card game based on Rock Paper Scissors- what is it called?

Tags: identify-this-game

A few years ago I played a fun multiplayer card game unashamedly based on Rock Paper Scissors.  The players each had a hand of cards that were "Rock", "Paper", or "Scissors", but there was text on the the cards that added extra powers and an added element of strategy.  Can't remember what it was called though.

I already searched Boardgamegeek for "Rock Paper Scissors" and googled it, but haven't been able to find anything that matches what I vaguely remember.

I know it's not much to go on, but anyone have a guess what game I played?

Comment: Are you sure, this isn't the game: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24260/rock-paper-scissors-card-game

Comment: If you like the game you describe, you might want to check out Custom Heroes. It's basically "President" with powerups like you describe.

Comment: "Rock Paper Scissors: The Card Game" can't be it because it's only two-player. We were 5 or more people sitting around a table.

Comment: Pyramid Arcade has a great rock-paper-scissors tournament game included. Doesn’t sound exactly like what you’re talking about though.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be [GG](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/188576/gg).
Was a [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/gizco/gg-an-addictive-strategy-card-battle-game) back in 2016.